# Show JSF validation error next to the fields

Tags: validation, jsf-2, message

I want to display the error messages beside the text fields.

I am able to show the error message but all the error messages come at once...

```
<h:form id="LoginForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" id="login">
                    <h2 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;">Login</h2>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"> 
                            <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Login Email:"></h:outputLabel>
                        </td>
                        <td class="field">
                            <h:inputText id="email"  size="20" maxlength="70" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your email,eg:yourid@domain.com" value="#{loginController.selected1.email}"> <f:validateLength maximum="70"></f:validateLength></h:inputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label">
                            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:"></h:outputLabel>
                        </td>
                        <td class="field">
                            <h:inputSecret id="password"  size="20" maxlength="50" required="true" requiredMessage="Please confirm your password" value="#{loginController.selected1.password}"><f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="50"></h:inputSecret>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h:commandButton value="Login" type="submit" action="#{loginController.checkValidUser()}"></h:commandButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>

    </h:form>
```

How to modify the code to show error messages beside the text fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put a `<h:message>` right there where you need to see it. E.g.

```
<tr>
    <td class="label"> 
        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Login Email:"></h:outputLabel>
    </td>
    <td class="field">
        <h:inputText id="email"  size="20" maxlength="70" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your email,eg:yourid@domain.com" value="#{loginController.selected1.email}"> <f:validateLength maximum="70"></f:validateLength></h:inputText>
        <h:message for="email" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr>
    <td class="label"> 
        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Login Email:"></h:outputLabel>
    </td>
    <td class="field">
        <h:inputText id="email"  size="20" maxlength="70" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your email,eg:yourid@domain.com" value="#{loginController.selected1.email}"> <f:validateLength maximum="70"></f:validateLength></h:inputText>
    </td>
    <td class="message">
        <h:message for="email" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I suggest to have a look at `<h:panelGrid>`. It minimizes the ugly HTML table boilerplate. Your code would then end up like follows:

```
<h:form id="LoginForm">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="label,field,message">
        <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Login Email:" />
        <h:inputText id="email" value="#{loginController.selected1.email}" size="20" maxlength="70" required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter your email,eg:yourid@domain.com">
            <f:validateLength maximum="70" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message for="email" />

        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginController.selected1.password}" size="20" maxlength="50" required="true" requiredMessage="Please confirm your password">
             <f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="50" />
        </h:inputSecret>
        <h:message for="password" />

        <h:panelGroup />
        <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginController.checkValidUser()}" />
        <h:panelGroup />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Do you recommend using hpanelgrid or using css for layout?

Comment: @Koray: This is offtopic to the question and non-constructive here. Try a chat box or a discussion forum instead. Note that CSS is a client side matter and that `<h:panelGrid>` is a server side component which generates a HTML `<table>` for the client side. So, your question can better be rephrased as "Do you recommend using table or CSS for layout?". JSF is thus completely irrelevant to the question. It would apply as good on every other server side language/framework which generates a bunch of HTML, like JSP, ASP, PHP, etc.